# dev/test/prod package update workflow for debian/ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, deb

I'm doing more ubuntu server work now (as opposed to RHEL), and I'm not certain how the debian/ubuntu communities handle managing package updates through a dev/test/(staging)/prod environment.

The workflow I would like is:

- apt-get upgrade the test server
- Run all required tests
- Dump a list of installed packages (or at least the recently installed) with version info
- Upgrade the production server based on the tested versions

This is to avoid the possibility of an update coming in during the test period, and getting installed on the production server without first going through Test.

What I think I'm looking for is something like `dpkg --get-selections` and `dpkg --set-selections`, but with specific versions. I can probably script this fairly easily, since apt-get accepts version info with the package name, but it seems like other people would already have a solution for this. I'd also rather not have the overhead of keeping a local mirror.

Comment: One common way this is done, is by running your own repository.

Comment: @Zoredache - yeah, I've done that with yum repos too, but it's something I'd like to avoid right now if possible.